# How can I filter through object using 2 separate fields as unique identifiers?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-field, field-mapping, iteration

I have a custom object (we'll call it `RS__c`), and it *theoretically* has a 1 to 1 relationship to `OpportunityLineItems` ([it is not possible to create a reference field directly to create this relationship](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000b5OAAAY)). So for the time being I have a lookup reference to the parent `Opportunity` object AND I have a simple text field that stores the `OpportunityLineItem.Id`

> The goal is to keep this custom object records in sync with their respective `OpportunityLineItem`.

At the moment I can easily `INSERT` a new `RS__c` line item when I `INSERT` an `OpportunityLineItem`, and even `UPDATING` is not difficult, BUT the problem occurs when we have an **orphan line item**. In order to sync `Opportunities` with QuickBooks we often need to delete the `Opportunity` and have it reinserted through 3rd party software. Naturally because of the lookup relationship between the `RS__c` and `Opportunity`, when this happens the relationship is severed with the Opportunity field gets cleared.

I have a another custom field that is unique to the quickbooks invoice, so when the `Opportunity` is reinserted I can determine the new Opportunity ID just fine, but if that `Opportunity` has 3 `OpportunityLineItems` then I cannot distinguish which `RS__c` line item each one belongs to. Once I've narrowed it down to these 3 orphan line items I would then need to use the `Product.ID` to determine which 'OpportunityLineItem`belongs to its respective`RS__c` line item.

I've considered complex mapping solutions but I'm not sure how I would create such an collection. For example something with this structure seems like something I could iterate through to maintain the relationships I need to reconcile my problem.

```
Map<QB.ID,Map<Product.ID,RS__c>>
```

Meanwhile, I've been attempting something like this, but am not sure how I would write the conditional statement to determine an orphan item based on `QB.ID` and `Product.ID`

```
/* If OLI exist, then update RS Line Item */
if(rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id) != NULL){
    rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id).Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
    rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id).Quickbooks_Id__c = opp.QB_Id__c;
    rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id).OpportunityLineItem_Id__c = oli.Id;
    rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id).Product__c = oli.Product2Id;
    rs_items.add(rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id));
    System.debug('::ADD EXISTING LINE ITEM:: '+rsLineItemByOpportunityLineItem.get(oli.Id));
} 
/* If OLI does NOT exist, then check for orphan line item */
else if (){
} 
/* If OLI exist, then update RS Line Item */
else {
    Refrigerant_Sale__c rs_item = new Refrigerant_Sale__c();
    rs_item.Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
    rs_item.Quickbooks_Id__c = opp.QB_Id__c; // Required field
    rs_item.OpportunityLineItem_Id__c = oli.Id;
    rs_item.Product__c = oli.Product2Id;
    rs_items.add(rs_item);
    System.debug('::ADD NEW LINE ITEM:: '+rs_item);
}
```

Just had a new thought towards a solution as I explained this... what if I create a formula or custom text field that uniquely joins the QB.ID and Product.ID as a means for having 1 unique identifier to filter by? ...

Well that's where I'm at with this, appreciate any advice that could help resolve this.

Comment: You can simulate a 1-1 Relationship between 2 Objects, `A__c` and `B__c`.  On each Object, have a lookup to the other one and ensure record `a` lookups to record `b` and `b` lookups to `a`.  That way you can always get each other's fields via the lookups no matter if you're on record `a` or record `b`.  ..... Theoretically possible with two Custom Objects though you can't create a Lookup on `OpportunityLineItem`

Comment: the general problem you have is that an Opportunity can have multiple OLIs for the same product (pricebookentry - PBE) and hence there is nothing unique about an OLI that you can use in `RS__c` when the Oppo is deleted/reinserted - unless your business logic prevents multiple OLIs on the same Oppo with the same PBE.

Comment: Correct, the only unique protocol we have in place is that no two OLIs will have the same Product attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I DID IT!**

As suspected towards the end of my OP, I created a separate formula field, (i.e. `RS__c.Sync_Id__c`), which concatenated the QB Id and the Product Id (18 character version). Once I had that it was easy to create a map that I could actually use to index through my logic like so:

```
/**
 * Map all active Refrigerant Sale line items based on unique Sync ID
 * @return Map<Sync_Id__c, Refrigerant_Sale__c>
 */
Map<String, RS__c> rsLineItemBySyncId = new Map<String, RS__c>();
for(RS__c rs : rsLineItemMap.values()){
    rsLineItemBySyncId.put(rs.Sync_Id__c, rs);
}
```

Now when I iterate through my Opportunity and OpportunityLineItems I can filter through existing RS line items like so:

```
for(Opportunity opp : invoices){
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : opportunityLineItemsByOpportunityId.get(opp.Id)){
        /* Populate Sync Id to verify orphan line items */
        String sync_id = opp.QB_Id__c+'-'+oli.Product2Id;

        /* Check for existing RS line items */
        if(rsLineItemBySyncId.get(sync_id) != NULL){
            // Update existing RS line item
        } else {
            // Add new RS line item
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, Possibly with External Id and Salesforce ID we can achieve your requirement. Check once...